# How can I unit test my meteor methods?

Tags: database, unit-testing, meteor

I've written some Meteor methods for my application containing various chunks of business logic. Now I'd like to write unit tests for those methods. By unit tests, I specifically mean fast tests which do not:

- Perform XHRs or
- Write to the database

How can I go about doing this? My current thinking is that when I start up the Meteor server in a test configuration I should replace my collections with dummy collections (by passing `new Meteor.Collection(null)`) and have my unit tests run on the server side, invoking Meteor.call() on each of my methods in turn from there. I'm not entirely sure how I'd kick off the tests, possibly I'd want to build a custom `/tests` URL into my application which fires them off. Does this approach seem reasonable? Are there any libraries/packages out there that would make writing unit tests for my methods easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, here's what I came up with to unit test my methods. I'll be the first to admit there's a lot of room for improvement in this!

First, in my `server.coffee` file I have the following code:

```
Meteor.startup ->
  return unless Meteor.settings["test"]
  require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require
  require("coffee-script")
  fs = require("fs")
  path = require("path")
  Mocha = require("mocha")

  mocha = new Mocha()
  files = fs.readdirSync("tests")
  basePath = fs.realpathSync("tests")
  for file in files
    continue unless file.match(/\.coffee$/) or file.match(/\.js$/)
    continue if file[0] == "."
    filePath = path.join(basePath, file)
    continue unless fs.statSync(filePath).isFile()
    mocha.addFile(filePath)
  mocha.run()
```

First of all this code only runs if Meteor.settings["test"] has been defined, which I can do when I run my tests locally, but which should never be true in production. It then searches the "tests" directory for javascript or coffeescript files (subdirectories aren't searched in my implementation, but it would be easy to add that) and adds them to a `mocha` instance. I'm using the excellent [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) javascript testing library here, combined with the [chai](http://chaijs.com/) assertion library.

All of this code is wrapped inside a `Meteor.startup` call so that my unit tests run on server start. This is especially nice because Meteor automatically re-runs my tests whenever I change any of my code. Because of the decision to isolate out the database and not perform XHRs, my tests run in a few milliseconds, so this isn't very annoying.

For the tests themselves, I need to do

```
chai = require("chai")
should = chai.should()
```

To pull in the assertion library. There are still a couple tricky problems to be solved, though. First of all, Meteor method calls will fail if they're not wrapped in a Fiber. I don't currently have a very good solution to this problem, but I created the `itShould` function to replace mocha's `it` function and wrap the test body inside a Fiber:

```
# A version of mocha's "it" function which wraps the test body in a Fiber.
itShould = (desc, fn) ->
  it(("should " + desc), (done) -> (Fiber ->
    fn()
    done()).run())
```

Next up is the problem of, for testing purposes, replacing my collections with mock collections. This is very difficult to do if you follow the standard Meteor practice of putting your collections in global variables. However, if you make your collections *properties* on a global object, you can do it. Simply make your collections via `myApp.Collection = new Meteor.Collection("name")`. Then, in your tests, you can have a `before` function mock out the collection:

```
realCollection = null
before ->
  realCollection = myApp.Collection
  myApp.Collection = new Meteor.Collection(null)
after ->
  myApp.Collection = realCollection
```

This way, your collection is mocked out for the duration of the test run, but then it's restored so you can interact with your app normally. Some other things are possible to mock via a similar technique. For example, the global `Meteor.userId()` function only works for client-initiated requests. I've actually filed [a bug](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/781) against Meteor to see if they can provide a better solution to this problem, but for now I'm just replacing the function with my own version for testing:

```
realUserIdFn = null
before ->
  realUserIdFn = Meteor.userId
  Meteor.userId = -> "123456"
after ->
  Meteor.userId = realUserIdFn
```

This approach works for some parts of Meteor, but not all of it. For example, I haven't found a way to test methods that invoke `this.setUserId` yet, because I don't think there's a good way to mock out that behavior. On the whole, though, this approach is working out for me... I love being able to re-run my tests automatically when I change the code, and running tests in isolation is just generally a good idea. It's also very convenient that tests on the server can block, making them simpler to write without callback chains. Here's what a test would look like:

```
describe "the newWidget method", ->
  itShould "make a new widget in the Widgets collection", ->
    widgetId = Meteor.call("newWidget", {awesome: true})
    widget = myApp.Widgets.findOne(widgetId)
    widget.awesome.should.be.true
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) for testing a bigger Meteor application I'm working on.  It can do much more than unit testing and it's been working fairly well.  A blog post about this is on my todo lis. For now I can give you this CoffeeScript:

```
if were_testing()
  describe 'something', ->
    it 'should be greater than 0', ->
      expect(theThing).toBeGreaterThan 0

were_testing = -> document.location.pathname.replace(/^\/([^\/]*).*$/, '$1') == 'tests'

jasmine_test = ->
  jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv()
  jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000

  htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter()
  jasmineEnv.addReporter htmlReporter

  jasmineEnv.execute()
```

This code runs in a browser. It's possible to run it in a casperjs instance if you want to script it.  Since it's going through a Meteor initialization on the client it will do XHR and database queries, but you can easily write tests that won't do any extra queries. Or write a subset of functions that is triggered when visiting /unittests

Our stuff is not in production yet but the deployscript simply deletes the above jasmine code and all `*.spec.coffee` files.

I want to plug this into Jenkins to get to a proper continuous integration setup but haven't found time to set up Jenkins more than the basics. I also played with using casperjs for headless browsing, which worked pretty well.

You can also take a different approach by putting your test code in `tests/` (not executed by Meteor) and then use `require`. I quickly tried this and found it quite tedious.

Comment: I might not be understanding this, but it looks like this code would run in the browser, right? In that case, I think it gets pretty difficult to test methods in isolation. Unless there's something special going on, your method calls are going to be doing XHRs and database writes and stuff, no?